# MongoDB find Documents where all array elements equal some value

Tags: mongodb

Collection:

```
db.test.find()
{
  { "_id" : ObjectId(...), "arr" : [ "Today", "is", null ] }
  { "_id" : ObjectId(...), "arr" : [ null, null, null ] }
}
```

I'm trying to find all documents where all of `arr` equals some value. In this example, I would want the document containing `arr : [null, null, null]` when given `null`.

[Find documents where ALL elements of an array have a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392534/find-documents-where-all-elements-of-an-array-have-a-specific-value)

This solution is close to what I want; however, my array data do not have keys for an `$elemMatch` to reference. Is there a way to accomplish this query without being unnecessarily costly or restructuring my data?

Thanks!

Comment: There is very similar question here as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` query operator. It just needs a query.

```
 db.test.find( { arr:  { $not: { $elemMatch: { $ne: null } } } } )
```

`"$elemMatch" + "$ne"`

This part includes all the documents where `arr` array don't have at least one null value.

These are all the documents which has at least one not null value.

`$not`

This part will keep the all the documents which are not in `"$elemMatch" + "$ne"`.

These are all the documents that has its all of values as `null`.

Please accommodate edge cases where field doesn't exist to make sure things work as expected.

Comment: This appears to work, with the addition of an exists and size check on arr. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator, but the semantics might not be exactly what you want.

```
db.test.find({ arr: { $all: [null] } })
```

That would return both of your test documents.

If you really want to query for an array with 3 null values, you can just query for the literal array:

```
db.test.find({arr:[null,null,null]})
```

Comment: Correct, the `$all` operator seems to return if any value is `null` (including `arr` itself). Unfortunately, it is unknown how many values an array will have, so I will be unable to construct a literal array for comparison.

Comment: It seems like an odd requirement. Perhaps there's another approach to solving. Can you share more details regarding your use case and examples?

Comment: Simply put, I need to be able to filter documents who have homogeneous data in an array. For example, say driver1 and driver2 have the following entries in db.drivers: `{_id: "driver1" , record: ["win", "win", "win"]}, {_id: "driver2", record: ["win"]}`. Given this data, I would want to query db.drivers for all drivers with a perfect record, which would return both in this case.