# Mongoose get all documents when all embedded/nested documents have property equal to

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection of Order model:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff2"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff1"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff2"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff1"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "buy"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
```

I want to retrieve the documents that **all** their embedded documents(items) have a status equal to `reserved` so when I run the query I must get:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
```

When I use the following query I get all the documents that contain even one status equal to `reserved` in their nested documents

```
var orders = await Order.find({"items.status": "reserved"}).exec()
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594636. For your case `Order.find( { items:  { $not: { $elemMatch: {status:{$ne: 'reserved' } }} } } )`

Comment: @Veeram thank you, your code worked just fine could you please just publish it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yw. I will mark this is duplicate. Please upvote if you like.